# Support for compact framework in subsonic 3.0?

Tags: .net, compact-framework, subsonic, subsonic3, sql-server-ce

I was wondering when support for compact framework and sql server compact edition will be added to the [Subsonic 3.0 project](http://subsonicproject.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Is the link below any use?

http://www.agilification.com/post/T4-Templates-For-The-NET-Compact-Framework.aspx

> ```
> T4 templates also do not work in a Smart Device project because the
> ```
>
> Compact Framework does not include the
>   System.CodeDom namespace. But I found
>   a way to make them work if you or your
>   readers are interested: (
>   http://www.agilification.com/post/T4-Templates-For-The-NET-Compact-Framework.aspx
>   ).

Answer (score 0):

I've got a custom build of Subsonic 3.0 working on .Net CF. It wasn't too hard - mostly just removing some method overloads, replacing some assumptions on the Linq side of things, and working up a custom build of Queryable and System.Linq.Expressions from the Mono project.

Comment: Is it available anywhere online?

Comment: @Charles: I'll search around for it. IIRC, it wasn't 100% complete, but I suspect it will be better than nothing.